# Handler in IIS7 Integrated mode not working

Tags: c#, .net, iis, httphandler, iis-8

My handler works perfectly if I set the extension to *.axd but if I set it to *.mp4 the handler is not called.

```
public class TestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

/test.axd will output "Hello World!" but /test.mp4 does not. There is a mime type inserted for .mp4 and the file itself can be served fine. Any ideas?

The web.config entry under system.webServer handlers looks like this:

add name="MP4Handler_Integrated" path="test.mp4" verb="*" type="Web.Handlers.TestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode"